# How to install home-brew from a python script?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

**Environment**

Python 3.7

Mac OS Catalina 10.15

**Problem**

This makes me crazy!

I need to install home-brew from my python script.
I tried different code and different commands.

**If I run it as admin, it says "Don't run this as root!"**

**If I run it as non-admin, it says "Need sudo access on macOS"**

This is my Python script:

```
def InstallHomeBrew(p_command):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(p_command, shell=True, stdout=True)
    (output, err) = proc.communicate()
    returncode_brew = proc.wait()
    print(f"returncode_brew : {returncode_brew}")

    if returncode_brew == 0:
        print("Homebrew installation was fine")
        print(f"Here is the succesfull command: {p_command}")
        return True

    else:
        print("Homebrew installation was not fine!")
        return False




# === Get actual username ====================
proc = subprocess.Popen("dscacheutil -q user | grep -A 3 -B 2 -e uid:\ 5'[0-9][0-9]'", shell=True,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
returncode_get_username = proc.wait()

username = proc.stdout.readlines()
# username = username.decode('utf-8')

for line in username:
    if isinstance(line, bytes):
        line = line.decode()

    if line.find("name") != -1:
        mac_account = line.replace('name: ', '').replace('\n', '')


# ====================================================================
# Here below the list of different commands my function will try for installing homebrew

command_install_homebrew_1 = f'/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"'
command_install_homebrew_2 = f'sudo -u {mac_account} /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"'
command_install_homebrew_3=f"""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "{os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),'PhoneBot_Install.sh')} args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'"""
command_install_homebrew_4 = f'sudo -S /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"'
command_install_homebrew_5=f"""/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "{os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]),'PhoneBot_Install_as_Admin.sh')} args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'"""
command_install_homebrew_6 = f'sudo /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"'


result_1 = InstallHomeBrew(command_install_homebrew_1)
if not result_1:
    result_2 = InstallHomeBrew(command_install_homebrew_2)
    if not result_2:
        result_3 = InstallHomeBrew(command_install_homebrew_3)
        if not result_3:
            result_4 = InstallHomeBrew(command_install_homebrew_4)
            if not result_4:
                result_5 = InstallHomeBrew(command_install_homebrew_5)
                if not result_5:
                    result_6 = InstallHomeBrew(command_install_homebrew_6)
```

This is the source code of bash script:

```
#Install.sh
sudo -S /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

#Install_as_Admin.sh
sudo /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

This is the output:

```
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user gauthierbtz to be an Administrator)!
returncode_brew : 1
Homebrew installation was not fine!
Need sudo access on macOS (e.g. the user gauthierbtz to be an Administrator)!
returncode_brew : 1
Homebrew installation was not fine!
Don't run this as root! (1)
returncode_brew : 1
Homebrew installation was not fine!
Password:mypassword123
Don't run this as root!
returncode_brew : 1
Homebrew installation was not fine!
Don't run this as root! (1)
returncode_brew : 1
Homebrew installation was not fine!
Don't run this as root!
returncode_brew : 1
Homebrew installation was not fine!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**So How can we install home-brew from a python script?**